# Upgrading an ASP.NET 2.0 to ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, visual-sourcesafe

We've got an older ASP.NET app written in VS 2005.  I'd like to upgrade it to VS 2008, but still leave the old one around, in case I need to do development in it.  It is also in Visual SourceSafe.  So, would I just get into VS 2008, do an Open Website from Source Control (or whatever the string is) and put it into a new website under wwwroot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open the application in VS 2008.  VS will automatically detect the app is VS 2005 and offer to upgrade, with a backup.  Do that.  *Usually* there aren't issues with an upgrade.

Comment: My biggest concern is all of the Crystal Reports we have in that app.  Right now, in order to make Crystal work I've had to include the Crystal Reports 11 R 2.MSM file in the setup and deployment project so that the server will have what it needs to generate the report.  (I'm sorry, I should have mentioned this in the original post.)

Comment: Why don't you try to do the conversion and find out?  You're project is in VSS, label the whole thing so you can get off the label if it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: You might need to get the VS2008 web deployment projects and create a new deployment project for your build.  Download it at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2008/01/25/announcing-rtw-of-visual-studio-2008-web-deployment-projects-wdp.aspx

Comment: OK, I'm going to give it a try. BTW, how is the new deployment project different from the one that came with VS 2008?

Comment: i never used VS 2005's version so I don't know from personal experience, however there is some information here that may be useful http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx